# Google Pay API поддерживает ли все устройства

Tags: android, google-pay

Нужно прикрутить оплату в Android приложение, все ли устройства могут поддерживать Google Pay Api. У сервиса используется шлюз Сбера, вот что говорят сами разработчики.
https://securepayments.sberbank.ru/wiki/doku.php/integration:api:schemes:googlepay_app_rest

Какие вообще условия должны быть для того чтобы Google Pay работал, или же я могу просто добавить Google Pay Api в свое приложение, не беспокоясь о том что на каких то устройствах оно может отвалиться

Comment: Ну как минимум в устройствах без гуглосервисов точно никакого Google Pay не будет. Или если девайс рутован, то провалится проверка SafetyNet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, вот что говориться о ограничениях в документации Google Pay Api:"Убедитесь, что на вашем устройстве Android установлены сервисы Google Play 18.0.0 или более поздней версии."